# Is there a Unicode symbol in BSTR?

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a WinAPI function that can tell whether there is a non-latin character in BSTR?

Comment: Define "non-Latin". Does é count? Or do you mean non-7-bit-ASCII?

Comment: @tadman: If the question is really about Unicode you might assume that yes, "LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE" is a Latin character ;-) But the title seems to use the word Unicode as synonymous with "non-Latin", which is nonsense. How does the questioner want to classify punctuation etc?

Comment: It's not always cut and dry what qualifies. If it falls in the [ISO-8859-1 Latin1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) table, it's technically "Latin", though there are all kinds of accented characters and punctuation in there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will presume that your question is really about whether there are characters in the string that require Unicode to represent, as opposed to ASCII. There are many Latin characters that can't be represented in ASCII.

There's no such function but it's trivial to write your own. Just go through the string character by character and make sure each value is less than 128. If you find any greater than or equal to 128, those are Unicode characters.

Comment: I know you're just using the questioners own wording, but I don't think it's helpful to only describe non-ASCII characters as "Unicode". The ASCII characters also have Unicode code points. Which I'm sure you know, but I'm not sure the questioner knows.

Comment: @SteveJessop, I thought I was being careful with my wording but I can see how someone might get that impression. Thanks for adding a clarification.